# Internet Explorer OL problem with decimals over 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, list

In my website, I've got an `ol` with decimals (`list-style-type:decimal`). In Internet Explorer, when the list gets over 9 the decibel starts at 0 again.

This is how it should be displayed, and how it's displayed in Firefox:
[image: OL in Firefox]


This is how Internet Explorer 7 and 6 displays it (IE8 not tested yet):
[image: OL in Internet Explorer]


So the list starts at zero again.

CSS of the list:

```
ol {
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-type:none;
}
ol li {
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-type:decimal;
    margin:5px 0 5px 23px;
}
```

edit: And my css reset file adds this (this comes from firebug):

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead {
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:0 none;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0;
    outline-color:-moz-use-text-color;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

Who knows how to fix this?

Comment: works for me in IE6. Don't you have another piece of CSS that could hide the start of the number?

Comment: Jerome: I get the same problem in IE6. I've overlooked the css coming from my css reset file. See my edit. If you still can't reproduce it, I'll post the link to the website where I've got the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers are cut off by the margin. Increase it, and you'll see the tens-place digits.

```
ol li {
    margin-left: 2.5em;
}
```

or you can modify it as

padding-left : 30px

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `margin:0;` in your css reset file.

Comment: The `margin:5px 0 5px 23px` in `ol li` should overwrite that.

Comment: It *should*, but we're talking about IE here ;) Remove it, and you'll see it works.

Comment: I got it: it is not enough because of the margin of 'ol'.

Comment: It should, and it does overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

A specific answer for users in the future who have this problem: the left margin has to be at least **30px** to display double digits in IE.